# Display 3d point

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I am trying to display 3d point (50,30,20) using opengl but noting is displayed on the screen. How can I solve it?

init:

```
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(20.0, 70.0, 10.0, 40.0, 10.0, 30.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
 

}
```

Display:

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPointSize();
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(50.0, 30.0, 20.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804807/display-3d-point-using-opengl

Comment: @KhanJuned The issue is related, but in this case it is slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point is clipped by the near plane of the orthographic projection:

```cpp
glOrtho(20.0, 70.0, 10.0, 40.0, 10.0, 30.0);
```

```cpp
glVertex3f(50.0, 30.0, 20.0);
```

The OpenGL coordinate system is a right handed system (see [Right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)). In view space the y axis points upwards and the x axis points to the right. Since the z axis is the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the x and y axis, it points out of the view.
Hence you've to shift the point along the negative z axis in between the near and far plane:

<s>`glVertex3f(50.0, 30.0, 20.0);`</s>

```cpp
glVertex3f(50.0, 30.0, -20.0);
```